# Zeitwerk constant missing when class moved into nested /public dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, zeitwerk

I'm refactoring here a classic Rails app into a packages/modularized structure using [packwerk](https://github.com/Shopify/packwerk). So what used to be:

```
- app
  - services
    - foo
```

turned into:

```
- packages
  - package_name
    - services
      - foo
```

I added the following line in `application.rb` for autoloading:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.load_defaults 6.0

  # packwerk files
  config.paths.add 'packages', glob: '*/{*,*/concerns}', eager_load: true
```

Until this point it worked fine and my `Foo` service was available at `Foo`.

But when I created a `/public` folder and moved services there (standard for packwerk):

```
- packages
  - package_name
    - public
      - services
        - foo
```

it stopped working and calling `Foo` started throwing `unitialized constant error`. Same for `PackageName::Services::Foo`, `PackageName::Foo`, etc.

Adding `zeitwerk.rb` initializer in case it's of any help, although I don't see there anything that could be causing the issue:

```
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  # See inflections.rb for inflector rules
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    "ai_wrapper" => "AIWrapper", # ActiveAdmin class
  )

  # ignore ActiveAdmin classes: without this line zeitwerk will match constants like Documents or DocumentFields
  # to /ops/admin classes instead of core/models directories
  autoloader.ignore(Rails.root.join('packages/ops/admin'))
end
```

Comment: What does `bin/rails runner 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` say?

Comment: it includes ```packages/package_name/public``` @XavierNoria

Comment: Does it include also `packages/package_name/public/services`?

Comment: solved @XavierNoria, thanks for your help. Constant was moved to ```Services::Foo```. I removed the namespace on the initializer with ```loader.collapse(Rails.root.join('packages/package_name/public/services'))```

Comment: Awesome. Let me ask a detail, the original description said `Services::Foo` was not found. Was it wrong perhaps?

Comment: Is that standard in packwerk? Or should you define new wildcard patterns so that `packages/package_name/public/services` is an autoload path and no collapsing is needed?

Comment: i must have missed ```Services::Foo``` when I was trying constants, @XavierNoria. Just removed it from the original description. Regarding packwerk, more common is to have all packages inside /app, then you don't need to reconfigure zeitwerk.

Comment: Fantastic @ntonnelier, I've summarized the solution below.

Comment: I'd recommend to test concerns, if there's any. Because if the pattern is the same and `public/concerns` does not exist,  a `Concerns::` namespace will be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding an intermediate `public` directory, the wildcard pattern made `packages/package_name/public` an autoload path, and therefore the constant expected to be defined in that file was now `Services::Foo`.

In order to define and use the same top-level `Foo` constant after the introduction of the new directory, the configuration can use a different wildcard pattern so that `packages/package_name/public/services` becomes an autoload path, or can alternatively stay with `packages/package_name/public` and collapse `services`.